# Can LaunchDarkly internally communicates with organization's external service for feature flag evaluation

Tags: android, ios, feature-flags, launchdarkly

Currently We are evaluating LaunchDarkly to incorporate. We have a specific use case like below.

1. App -> LD (LaunchDarkly)
2. LD -> My-Own-Service  // feature flag evaluation based on context params passed to my server side.
3. My-Own-Service -> LD // sends result back.
4. LD -> App. //LD notifies App.

Please let me know if this is possible.

Prior Evaluation what I Did:

1. I have gone through the Integrations tab in LD site after login to see a possible integration is given. I have not found one. Or I missed it or misread it.

I know you can ask me why this way, you can talk to ur service directly  :-)// ignore this.